# casting does not work on nested list object type and returns empty lists (List<List<Integer>>)

Tags: java, list, arraylist, casting

I'm doing some leetcode challenges related to backtracking, namely:
https://leetcode.com/problems/permutations/

Where I need to return `List<List<Integer>>` as the type, however my `List<List<Integer>>` only gets populated correctly if I accept `List<Integer>` as my parameter and I cast it to `ArrayList<Integer>` while I add it in the main result.

**Code**:

```
    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<List<Integer>> permute(int[] nums) {
        bt(new ArrayList<Integer>(), nums);
        return result;
    }
    
    public void bt(List<Integer> tmp, int[] nums){
        if(tmp.size() == nums.length){
            result.add(new ArrayList<>(tmp));  // HERE
        }else{
          // some logic here
            
        }
    }
```

**Output**:
[[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]]

**Versus, the code below where i accept ArrayList as the parameter**

**Code:**

```
List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();   
public List<List<Integer>> permute(int[] nums) {
    bt(new ArrayList<Integer>(), nums);
    return result;
}
public void bt(ArrayList<Integer> tmp, int[] nums){
    if(tmp.size() == nums.length){
        result.add(tmp); // HERE
    }else{
      ... some logic here
    
    }
}
```

**Output:** [[],[],[],[],[],[]]

Comment: `ArrayList` is a type reference,so you must use `new ArrayList<>(tmp)` here,otherwise `tmp` value will changes in each recursive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no casting in your code, and it doesn't matter if your method accepts a `List<Integer>` or an `ArrayList<Integer>`.

What matters it that in the first snippet you add a copy of the input list `tmp` to the result (`result.add(new ArrayList<>(tmp))`) while in the second snippet you add a reference to the original `tmp` list (`result.add(tmp)`).

In the latter case, if you later make changes in the list referenced by `tmp`, these changes are reflected in all the elements of the `result` list, since they are all references to the same list object.